# Resgatar registros de horários de uma data específica e calcular intervalo entre horários

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com uma dúvida de como montar a lógica para calcular diferença de horas/minutos.

Eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
{timestamp}          {tipo}
2018-10-18 02:22:35    O
2018-10-18 02:22:34    OI
2018-10-18 02:22:32    II
2018-10-18 02:22:31    I
```

Onde o primeiro valor é um campo `timestamp` e o segundo o campo `tipo`.

**Edição 1**
Esse campo `tipo` é para determinar se o horário é entrada, saída ou intervalo. Sendo:

```
I  = Entrada
II = Intervalo
OI = Retorno Intervalo
O  = Saída
```

Quero calcular a diferença de tempo do "I" com o "O", diminuindo com a diferença de "II" e "OI".

Formatar e pegar apenas os horários eu consigo fazer tranquilamente com o Carbon.

O meu problema maior está sendo em como comparar o `tipo` (saber qual o primeiro e qual o último) e também como não misturar os dias, afinal existem mais resultados. Ou seja, a minha consulta retorna registros de vários dias e estou com dificuldade para separar somente os registros de um dia específico, para poder aplicar os cálculos de diferença entre os horários daquele dia.

**Edição 2**

```php
$points = Records::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

$groupByDay = $points->sortBy('date');

    $result = $groupByDay
        ->groupBy(function ($result, $key) {
            return $result->created_at->format('d');
        });
```

Retorna:

```
  Collection {#269 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    18 => Collection {#285 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▶]
    }
    17 => Collection {#264 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

A ideia seria eu montar uma tabela, com o dia, hora inicial, hora final e esse tempo que seria o resultado do cálculo acima.

Se alguém pudesse me ajudar a pensar na LÓGICA da coisa eu já ficaria eternamento grato.

Comment: Mas qual o objetivo desse segundo campo 'tipo' (esse é o nome do campo?) e quais valores ele pode conter? Ele terá sempre letras apenas, e a ordem é alfabética? E, deixa eu ver se eu entendi: Dada uma data, 18/10/2018, por exemplo, você quer subtrair o menor horário do maior horário daquele dia (max - min), e depois, desse resultado, você quer subtrair todos os intervalos que existem entre o menor e o maior horários daquele dia?

Comment: Obrigado pelo interesse, esse tipo pode ter aqueles 4 valores apenas, ele mostra se é entrada, intervalo, volta do intervalo ou saída.

Comment: Você pode postar na pergunta o trecho de código que você já tem? Eu entendi melhor o problema agora, mas ainda não compreendi exatamente qual é a sua dúvida. Você já está conseguindo retornar esses registros de horários de uma determinada data? Você não sabe o código para fazer a matemática para subtrair esses horários?

Comment: Ai que esta, não estou conseguindo montar a lógica disso, estou apenas recebendo todos os registros do usuário, queria saber como vou pegar, os 4 registros do dia x para calcular, lembrando que não passo um dia como parâmetro específico, pois vou ter que calcular para todos os registros do sistema (no caso todos os dias).

Comment: Então, mas como você recebe esses registros? Como eles estão? Em um array? Como eu disse, posta um trecho do código na sua pergunta, que ficará mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Sim, cada registro possui um record_id, type, date (timestamp), e um id de quem criou. O retorno é em um array com todos os registros.

Comment: Pensei em de alguma forma, agrupar os registros por data, sendo 4 registros por data permitido, eu teria todos os tipos agrupados pela data. Isso seria coerente?

Comment: Momentaneamente, consegui agrupar os 4 registro de um dia. $points = Records::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get(); $pointsByDate = $points->groupBy('date');